# How to distinguish the which callback run rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am using same method in two callbacks `before_destroy` and `before_update`. Inside the method how can I check that which callback is called this method?

**My callbacks:**

```
before_destroy :set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
before_update :set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
```

**This is my callback method:**

```
def set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
  if destroy_callback
     # code here
  else
     # code here
  end
end
```

I am doing this because 90% code is same for both the callback but for `before_destroy` I need to skip one condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find which action this transaction belongs to

see this method [transaction_include_action?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/transaction_include_action%3F)

However you can't find which callback it is i.e `after_create` or `before_create` but it makes sure that this transaction belongs to `create` action.

In your case it can be used as follows,

```
if transaction_include_action?(:update)
...
else transaction_include_action?(:destroy)
...
end
```

Note:- This method is deprecated in Rails4. And the new method introduced `transaction_include_any_action?(actions)` which accepts an array of actions. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L433)

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you to split it?

```
class YourModel

  before_destroy :on_destroy_set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
  before_update :on_update_set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee

  def on_destroy_set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
    set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee(true)
  end

  def on_update_set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
    set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee
  end

  private

  def set_manager_to_true_of_any_trainee(destroying=false)
  end

end
```

Comment: I already know about this solution. But if I go with that solution I have to same data fetching code on both `callback` method and then send it to method.

Comment: So what you want is if one is executed, it shouldn't execute the other one?